# Function not calling in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

```
$.get('/share_win/get_contacts/',function(data){ alert("HELLO"); });
```

What is wrong in this AJAX call?  I'm not giving any error, but it does not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be ok. Check out the network tab in browser's developer tools. The page you are trying to get probably has some kind of error in the response.

Comment: I think it call get_contacts, after then jumped out from get function, because when I'm doing something wrong in get_contacts, errors appear when get is calling

Comment: You can try to add error callback to see if it gets triggered

`$.get('/share_win/get_contacts/',function(data){ alert("HELLO"); }).fail(function(error){
alert('error');
});`

Comment: So inspect what's happening. Use for example Google Chrome Dev tools (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Open the Network tab before you perform the ajax request. The response will be red and when you click on it, you can see more details.